# How to show running total if value is null for the month in PowerPivot Dax?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, calculation

I need a pivot table which shows the running total by month of each category. I am able to do it through a DAX measure. However, it does not show the running total if the aggregate value is not available in the pivot.

Data and pivot desired like below:

[image]

[image]

The Measure I am using is outlined below:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( SampleData[Num of reports] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( SampleData[Month] ),
        SampleData[Month]
            <= MAX ( SampleData[Month] )
    )
)
```

Comment: please post the code of your DAX measure.

Comment: =CALCULATE(SUM(SampleData[Num of reports]),FILTER(ALL(SampleData[Month]),SampleData[Month]<=MAX(SampleData[Month])))

Comment: You need to add Calendar table to your data model, connect it to the main data table, and re-design your measure to use dates from the calendar, not from transactions. https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/calendar-table-explained/

Comment: I am still not able to do it. I am very new to DAX, would you please guide me step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the option to show "0" in place of empty cells. You get this done by **UN-checking** the box "For empty cells show" in PivotTable options.

See image below:

**Note:** You can also show a custom text like "-"(hyphen) instead of 0 
[image: Show 0]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, this is not what I am looking for.. In the desired table, you can check that for Feb 2019 , there is value "1" as there were no item for the month of Feb 2019, it is showing total of Jan 2019 total only.